# Beamer Change Formatting of Notes

Tags: beamer, color, notes

I use the documentclass `beamer` and would like to have all my notes of the PDF in bold and red (- or a better solution on this problem).

Situation: I have notes once in a while when they seem important to me - not as a general guideline. On my small laptop screen, I just don't notice them popping up:

[image: screenshow]

How can I set this globally properly?

I already scrambled together `\AtBeginNote{\color{red}\bfseries}` but that feels like a hack.

---

Appendix:

```latex
\documentclass{beamer}

\usepackage{pgfpages}
\setbeameroption{show notes}
\setbeameroption{show notes on second screen=right}

\begin{document}

\begin{frame}
    Frame
    \note{Don't forget this!}
\end{frame}

\begin{frame}
    Next frame
\end{frame}

\end{document}
```

```bash
pdfpc --notes=right beamer.pdf
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
\documentclass{beamer}

\setbeameroption{show notes on second screen=right}

\setbeamerfont{note page}{series=\bfseries}
\setbeamercolor{note page}{fg=red}

\begin{document}

\begin{frame}
    Frame
    \note{Don't forget this!}
\end{frame}

\begin{frame}
    Next frame
\end{frame}

\end{document}
```

Comment: Awesome! Thank you!

Comment: @Suuuehgi You're welcome!